# Configuração da tag CORS no WEB.CONFIG em projeto .NET

Tags: xml, visual-studio, web.config

Estou com um problema na tag CORS no meu XML. Ele até reconhece no Visual Studio 2012, porém no VS 2017 ele compila mas não depura. As bibliotecas estão instaladas, mas ainda persiste no erro, mesmo ele rodando perfeito no VS 12.

Existe alguma outra alternativa para a tag? o que posso fazer para reconhecer?

Erro ao depurar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Forma como estou utilizando:
[image: Forma como estou utilizando]

Erro acontecendo no VS 17:
[image: Erro acontecendo no VS 17]

Pesquisei o erro quando estou depurando a solução:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O chaveamento do seu Web.config está errado, você deve colocar assim:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo